# Converting F distribution to t distribution

Tags: statistics, central-limit-theorem

Although I am aware of the relationship "square of the t distribution is F distribution", I'm having a little trouble applying it to the following problem:

Use the t table to find the 80th percentile of the F$_{1,30}$ distribution.

Even if I use a simple function call in r to find the quartile of t$_{30}$ at 80th percentile, and square it, it is not equal to F$_{1,30}$ . Am I misinterpreting the relationship?

Comment: Given 'a' as the probability, then $F(1-a,1,n) = t\big(\frac{1-a}{2},n\big)^2$. This is taken from several standard statistics texts.

Comment: Thanks for the correction!

Comment: Sorry, have to rescind.  I re-checked the source, (Schaum's Prob/Stat Theorem 4.9 (3rd ed)) and the form is what I had indicated.  If a = 0.05, F(0.95, 1,10) = 4.96; t(0.975,10) = 2.23 (Sqrt(F)).  The form given in the source is what I had written.  F(1-a,1, n) = t(1-a/2,10)^2.  But thanks for making me re-verify.

Comment: But I do see where I think you were coming from -- the ambiguity of the 'a' probability.  If the probability is defined as 95%, (1 - a) = 0.05., then your form is correct (1-0.95)/2 = 0.025.  The difference is if the 'a' probability is referring to the tail or not.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If $X\sim t(\nu)$, then $Y:=X^2\sim F(1,\nu)$. The $\alpha$ quantile of $Y$ is the positive number $q_{1,\nu,\alpha}$ such that
$$\mathbb P(Y\leqslant q_{1,\nu,\alpha})=\alpha. $$
Since $x^2 \leqslant a$ if and only if $|x|\leqslant a^{\frac12}$, we have
\begin{align}
\frac45&=\mathbb P\left(Y\leqslant q_{1,30,\frac45}\right)\\
&= \mathbb P\left(|X|\leqslant q_{1,30,\frac45}^{\frac12}\right)\\
&= 1-2\mathbb P\left(X\leqslant -q_{1,30,\frac45}^{\frac12}\right),
\end{align}
where the last inequality follows from symmetry of the $t$ distribution. Hence
$$P\left(X\leqslant -q_{1,30,\frac45}^{\frac12}\right)=\frac1{10}, $$
and the $t$-table yields $-q_{1,30,\frac45}^{\frac12} \approx -1.310415$. It follows that $q_{1,30,\frac45}\approx 1.717188$.